# Does Google Wallet offer an API for generating Virtual OneTime Cards for use by 3rd party commerce platforms?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-processing, android-pay

A client of mine has a very interesting use case:

Enabling consumers to be issued a temporary one-time use debit card number for purchasing goods on 3rd party retailers. Think pinterest for shopping, enabling one to ping goods from 3rd party retailers, and have a digital wallet for the purpose of purchasing pinned goods. *The key is that the 3rd party retailer does not necessarily implement an existing wallet solution, like google wallet. Think luxury goods.*

It seems that Google Wallet sort of, kind of, enables such a use case via its Virtual OneTime Cards. However, I could not find any indication of API endpoints that would work sort of like this:

Issue a POST to wallet.google.com/virtual_card with customer data, get back a 16-digit debit card number, that may then be used by customer to purchase items on 3rd party retailer sites.

It also seems that [AMEX Serve](https://www.serve.com/) has some kind of beta program in the works: http://techcrunch.com/2011/10/09/american-express-to-release-an-api-for-digital-wallet-platform-serve-focuses-on-data-and-personalization/

Visa has [v.me.](https://www.v.me/)

Of course, it doesn't seem like any of these services have APIs for issuing temporary debit cards.

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1):

The Google Wallet for online commerce API is probably what you're looking for:

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/faq

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/online/overview